# Program entry self-identification

Tags: c, linux, assembly

Is it possible for a program written in C (or assembly) and is linked with c stdlib using gcc to print the address of its entry? (Since the _start symbol denotes the program entry actually i ask if its possible to print the address of that symbol from inside the main function without using parsing of ELF executable file.)?

Comment: You can use built-ins to get an address in the entry function from the stack frame, but not the start address. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html Why do you want the start address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very portable(i.e. works on my machine, though maybe it's because the stars are aligned)

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void _start();

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("%p\n",_start);

    return 0;
}
```

On a RHEL 5.5 x86_64 box, the address printed matches the address entry point in the elf header, I'd not be surprised if this blows up if the binary is built to use address space randomization.

Answer (score 2):

I question why you need to do this, but have you tried using `dlsym` for your purposes?

Comment: i just wanted to know if it can be done, don't know if it has a practical aspect. What is the dlsym section in ELF?

Comment: dlsym is a function that gives you back an address based on the symbol name. e.g. void *p = dlsym(handle,"_start");

Answer (score 1):

```
extern void _start();
printf("%p\n", (void *)_start);
```

This is not "portable" in the sense that the C language defines no such thing as a `_start` function, but assuming it's implemented that way, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not in any portable way, no.

Using assembly for a known platform, you could probably step backward on the call stack, and write the return address (which should be inside the `_start` routine, if your platform uses such) to a variable accessible from the C side.

Of course, then you'd only have the address of the instruction following the `call` to your `main()`, not the *start* of the `_start` routine.